# Looping through strings in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, xpath

I'm trying to run the code below to take a list of URLs (in the file out.txt) and pulls the text content from that page, using xpath. The code finds the domain from the URL, then looks up the domain in a json file I've created that has both domain and Xpath. The xpath is then used to find the content.

However, right now if I run the code outside of the loop it works fine (page = 200). But if I do it inside the loop I'm getting page=404.

I'm sure that this is a grammar error with the loop and is probably really simple. What am I doing wrong?

```
URLList = open("out.txt").readlines()
for item in URLList:
    inputurl = item
    print (inputurl)
    type(inputurl)

    #this takes a URL and finds the xpath - it uses an external 
    domainlookup.json that is manually created
    # inputurl = input("PLEASE PROVIDE A URL FROM AN APPROVED DOMAIN: ")
    t = urlparse(inputurl).netloc
    domain = ('.'.join(t.split('.')[1:]))

    with open('domainlookup.json') as json_data:
        domainlookup = json.load(json_data)

    for i in domainlookup:
        if i['DOMAIN'] == domain:
             xpath = (i['XPATH'])

    #this requests the xpath from the URL and scrapes the text content

    page = requests.get(inputurl)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    content = tree.xpath(xpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find what's wrong with your code using this code:

```
URLList = open("out.txt").readlines()
for item in URLList:
    inputurl = item
    print("[{0}]".format(inputurl) )
```

As you can see from the output you're not removing **new line character** from the URL that's why `requests` can't load it later. Just `strip()` it before using:

```
inputurl = item.strip()
```